# rply2 running 32 bit r instead of 64 bit

Tags: r, jupyter

I've installed rply2 on a 64 bit system. 
Has anyone been able to change the r version used in the jupyter notebook from 64 down to 32? I'm trying to run an r library which only works with 32 bit r. The library is ROBDC connecting to a 32 bit data source